# In python3.6, opencv imread cannot read "png" image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am using windows 10, and I installed anaconda along with python 3.6. I got source files of opencv-python from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv, and I downloaded "opencv_python‑3.3.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl" and installed it. It worked fine for a few days untill "cv2.imread" cannot read "png" image while it works fine for "jpg" images.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

I tried to uninstall opencv with the command

```
!pip uninstall opencv-python
```

in anaconda ipython environment, but it did not work, because access was denied. How can I uninstall opencv? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look into your "Site-Packages" folder and delete all opencv folder manually. Or do you installed opencv in another directory? Then you have to look there.